# What is this description language used to explain Json Syntax?

Tags: json, syntax, modeling, flowchart

Although I can guess what the folllowing pictorial represents, but could you tell me what is the technical name of this language and how is it read?

[image: ]([![enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsMYZ.png)

Is there any difference between  the inward and outward quarter circles?

Soure: [Json](https://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a representation of EBNF (or BNF) as a [railroad diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram). The JSON diagrams are similar to those used to describe the syntax for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html).

These diagrams, as standards (or quasi-standards) were likely produced using Tex, with possibly the PSTricks, pst-node, or PGF/Tikz packages, as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14133), for JSON, and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124726), for SQLite.

> ... how is it read?

Like a train following the tracks. It's that simple for JSON.

Railroad diagrams have been used to describe the Pascal and Fortran 77 languages. In these cases, additional complexity comes from shear number of diagrams, but each of the diagrams is as easy to understand as the others. (However, those diagrams were likely hand-drawn or drafted).

> Is there any difference between the inward and outward quarter circles?

No.